# How to save the data using wampp in android?

Tags: android, database, wordpress, web-services, wamp

In my app there is an option for "saved items" like in Gmail. If the user wishes to save the current page data they can save from Android app, to try this, as told by some of my friends I installed wamp and wordpress and created a database.

Now the problems is I dont know how to carry on to the next step, has anybody done this?

Comment: What's your exact doubt? You are unable to communicate from Android to wampp and save the data in database?

Comment: Current page data i shud save in "saved items" box from android app @Appu

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Wordpress for this.

You need to write an API in something like PHP. This PHP API will allow you to make requests/send data from your Android app. The data received by the PHP API will then be stored in you MySQL database. This API should also have a function to be able to return data to the Android app when requested.

[Here](http://brenelz.com/blog/how-to-create-a-simple-api-with-php-and-mysql/) is a very simple guide on creating a simple API. You should use JSON, ignore the XML section.

Comment: my website is on wordpress, n when the user want to save the current page data thy can do it, n next time after login the saved items shud b in "saved" box this function will take place in android app @conor

Comment: Do you already have an existing website built in Wordpress? Are you saying that in your existing site, users can save items. You then want the saved items to appear in the app? If this is the case then you need to create a plugin for Wordpress.

Comment: s conor exactly that s the issue, bt wat plugin shud i use? @conor